# How to return the content of std::pair?

Tags: c++, return, return-value

I am trying to return content of `std::pair` which has `int` and `string` values.
What return type for function should I keep?

I tried with both `int` and `char` return type but gives error for both. I have given error below:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<map>
#include<vector>

    std::pair<int,std::string>client()  
{

std::vector<std::string> most { "lion","tiger","kangaroo",
                                 "donkey","lion","tiger",
                                 "lion","donkey","tiger"
                                 };
std::map<std::string, int> src;
for(auto x:most)
    ++src[x];

std::multimap<int,std::string,std::greater<int> > dst;

std::transform(src.begin(), src.end(), std::inserter(dst, dst.begin()), 
                   [] (const std::pair<std::string,int> &p) {
                   return std::pair<int,std::string>(p.second, p.first);
                   }
                 );

std::multimap<int,std::string>::iterator it = dst.begin();

 for(int count = 0;count<3 && it !=dst.end();++it,++count)
   std::cout<<it->second<<":"<<it->first<<std::endl;

 return *it;  
}

int main()
{
std::multimap<int,std::string>::const_iterator rec;
rec= client();  // Error  no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘rec = client()()’
std::multimap<int,std::string>::iterator it = rec.begin();  //error: ‘std::multimap<int, std::basic_string<char> >::const_iterator’ has no member named ‘begin’

 for(int count = 0;count<3 && rec !=it.end();++it,++count) // error: has no member named 'end' 
   std::cout<<rec->second<<":"<<rec->first<<std::endl;

}
```

Comment: Erm, return the pair itself?

Comment: `std::pair<int, std::string> client()` ?

Comment: If you have C++11, use auto keyword.

Comment: @NeilKirk: can you please tell me what `for(auto x:most)
    ++src[x];` does?

Comment: @Karimkhan Increase the int associated with the string x. It begins at 0.

Comment: You should use const auto& to avoid copying the string.

Comment: @NeilKirk: thanks. In above case `x`  would have content of `most` right?

Comment: @Karimkhan Yes, x will be each string in most in ascending order.

Comment: @NeilKirk: ok, and incrementing `++src` increment int associated with x or what?

Comment: Yes, I think I already explained that..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just return the pair of `int` & `std::string` itself 
as the `multimap` contains that as its element

```
std::pair<int,std::string> client(){
//...  
}
```

Comment: till it gives long error message, I could not figure where is the error!

Comment: @Karimkhan, You have to insert the element, not assign it.

Comment: @Karimkhan I think you took my code from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18547612/1870232)  So if you want to return the iterator to first element you need to use `std::multimap<int,std::string>::iterator client()  {...return it;}`
Also in question title this is not asked :P

Comment: @chris I think OP needs top three elements, similar question was asked yesterday

Comment: @P0W: thanks a lot, what silly mistake I am making so `error: ‘std::multimap<int, std::basic_string<char> >::const_iterator’ has no member named ‘begin’` comming ?

Comment: @Karimkhan If you keep on changing your code, the answers won't make any sense. Tell use what you exactly want ? You can't use iterators like that. I assume you want the `dst` map contents why not simply return the `multimap` ? You might want to start a new thread with clear questions and errors

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return the map entry (i.e., both the key and value), then just use `std::pair<int, std::string>` as the return type, as other answers mentioned.

If you want to just return the key, return `it->first` (and use `int` as the return type). If you want to return just the value, return `it->second` (and use `std::string` as the return type).

Comment: till it gives long error message, I could not figure where is the error!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return the a value from a `std::map` I would not explicitly use `std::pair` (though it is perfectly fine to do so). Personally I would use the `std::map::value_type` which represents the type of the values stored in the map (note: all containers have a type member called `value_type` that represents the type being stored).

```
std::multimap<int,std::string>::value_type client()
{
     // STUFF
     std::multimap<int,std::string>::iterator it = dst.begin();

     // STUFF;
     return *it;   // Note: this is UB if it == dst.end()
}
```

The reason I would use `value_type` rather than `std::pair` is normally I would not use explicit types but would have created typedefs (so it looks like this).

```
typedef std::multimap<int,std::string>  MapForX; // Modification to map here
                                                 // Will automatically roll threw all
                                                 // the following code as everything
                                                 // is defined in terms of `MapForX`

MapForX::value_type client()
{
     // STUFF
     MapForX::iterator it = dst.begin();

     // STUFF;
     return *it;   // Note: this is UB if it == dst.end()
}
```

Now if I change the type of the `MapForX`. Then I only have to change one thing (the single typedef). If you return `std::pair<int,std::string>` then you have to make changes in two places (the typedef and the return value). Which to me is redundant change that can cause problems.

As a demo: If you return `std::pair<int, std::string>` your code looks like this:

```
typedef std::multimap<int,std::string>  MapForX; // Modification to map here
                                                 // Will automatically roll threw MOST
                                                 // the following code.

// But notice this return type is not defined in terms of MapForX
// Thus if you change MapForX you will also need to change the return type.
// to match the correct type.
std::pair<int, std::string> client()
{
     // STUFF
     MapForX::iterator it = dst.begin();

     // STUFF;
     return *it;   // Note: this is UB if it == dst.end()
}
```

That works perfectly well. But in the future you have to make some changes. And you change the type of the map too `int => MySpecialType`. Now in my second example (with the typedef) you only need to make one change (in MapForX). In the example above you need to make two changes (one for MapForX and one std::pair on the return type).

Comment: thanks, nice explaination. but I could not get exactly why second code needed?

Comment: @Karimkhan: Its not "needed". But to make code easier to read and update it is sometimes easier to typedef types. The question is do you think it makes it easier to read. If you do then use the typedef. If you don't then use the full typename. It is a personal preference on readability. But as your types get more complex this technique comes in handy.

Answer (score 0):

@Martin York: You have good intentions but have you checked them against reality? Because `value_type` is exported as `std::pair<const key_type, mapped_type>`:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map

This may work if you return a copy of a pair from an iterator.  It won't work if you construct that pair within the function and then try to fill it because `first` can't be modified.

When the goal is to avoid the k/v types twice:

```cpp
using the_map_value_type = std::pair<the_map::key_type, the_map::mapped_type>
```

Then use this type as a function result. Of course, only until the negligence has been eliminated in the STL with an export like `detached_value_type`.