# failed to determine the correct return type

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, auto

I have the following simplified files and classes:

Stat.h:

```
class Stat
{
  auto getMinMaxValue(std::unordered_map< int, int >&);
};
```

Stat.cpp:

```
auto Stat::getMinMaxValue(std::unordered_map< int, int >&m)
{
  return std::minmax_element(m.begin(), m.end(), [](const pair<int, int>& p1, const pair<int, int>& p2) { return p1.second < p2.second; });
}
```

StatCount.h:

```
class StatCount : public Stat
{   
  void setWeight(std::vector<D> const&, const std::string);
};
```

StatCount.cpp:

```
void StatCount::setWeight(vector<D> const& ref, const string type)
{
    auto a = Stat::getMinMaxValue(m_value);
    cout << "MIN: " << a.first->second << endl;
    cout << "MAX: " << a.second->second << endl;
}
```

Since i declare the function "getMinMaxValue" into the base class Stat if i use the auto return type i got an error:

```
function 'getMinMaxValue' with deduced return type cannot be used before it is defined
```

but i failed to remove the auto return type and find the correct syntax to specify the return type of the method "getMinMaxValue"

if i read the documentation on cppreference i see it must be a pair of iterator but how ?

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18559452/how-to-return-the-content-of-stdpair

Comment: Might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/40694607/10077

Comment: @FredLarson: it is not a duplicate, i dont search a solution to keep the "auto", i want to find the correct declaration of the return type of the method minmax_element

Comment: @BoPersson, i think you did not read my question entirely, i dont understand why you said it is a duplicate, i dont search a solution to keep the "auto", i want to find the correct declaration of the return type of the method minmax_element...

Comment: Ok, I triggered on the error message and didn't notice that you have continued your research. Sorry. Reopening again.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=62aa80b71794f496

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i respond to myself, it seems i have found the solution:

Stat.h:

```
std::pair<std::unordered_map< int, int >::iterator, std::unordered_map< int, int >::iterator> getMinMaxValue(std::unordered_map< int, int >&);
```